# "Solr start" resets the schema and solrconfig file

Tags: solr, content-editor

As per Sitecore documentation for setting up Solr, I have generated the `schema.xml` (using managed-schema file) and updated `solrconfig.xml`. I copied both the files to the conf folder of the all cores and removed managed-schema. But when I stop the solr and start using command "solr start", it reset the `solrconfig.xml` changes, put the managed-schema file back and converted `schema.xml` as backup file (`schema.xml.bak`) in all the cores.

I am getting error while opening Content Editor and it seems to be due to issue with core. I am using SItecore 8.2 update 6.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.

solrconfig.xml of core needs to have below configuration setting.

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a schema.xml file by duplicating and renaming the managed-schema file.

Make the following changes in the default schema.xml file distributed with Solr **before generating Sitecore schema**:
Enclose all  and  elements in the  tag.
Enclose all  elements in the  tag.

Switch to the ClassicIndexSchemaFactory setting by adding the following line to the SolrConfig.xml file.

More details on this Sitecore knowledge base: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Generally, Solr shouldn't change your configuration/schema files unless you are enabling Master/Slave architecture, and you are trying to do these changes on Slave.